# Using "down to" to talk about code optimization

Tags: phrase-usage

I have recently optimized a code that resulted in a considerable reduction in runtime. I wanted to explain this to my manager. I have written a sentence structured as following.

The runtime of the code for the parametric study simulation (previously 9 hrs) **is** now **down to** 40 minutes.

I am wondering if "be down to" can be used in this sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly idiomatic to use 'down to' to discuss a quantity, measurement, amount, etc, that has reduced from a previously higher level.

> My weight was 95 kilos in March this year; now it is down to 82
> (true).
>
> The temperature was 32 degrees Celsius at noon; now it is down to 28 (also true).
>
> Our stock of coal was ten tonnes last year; now it down to eight. (invented).

You will note that the units (kilos, degrees, tonnes) can be omitted after the second, lower figure.

Comment: I am not wasting away; I have been eating salads and walking a lot, due to wifely pressure.

Answer (score 1):

"The runtime of the code for the parametric study simulation (previously 9 hrs) is now down to 40 minutes." is entirely correct.

"is now" emphasizes you're talking about the present state.
"down to" emphasizes this was a reduction in run time.

If your manager knows it used to take a long time, and you want to make the sentence shorter and clearer, you have the *option* of eliminating "(previously 9 hrs)", but you can also leave that in.  If you were writing a formal report, it's often better to avoid using parentheses.